# can't get Laravel Socialite to work with YouTube

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I'm getting "403 Insufficient permission" for YouTube. I, however, have enabled Goolge+ API & YouTube Data API from console.
It's working fine for Google+ but not for YouTube.

```
$scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
];
return Socialite::with('youtube')->redirect();
```

Am I missing something. Please suggest.

Comment: Google+ and YouTube are from same company but have different departments, may be you need to get separate  access for youtube

Comment: I got it solved but I got a different issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049969/not-receiving-refresh-token-even-in-the-first-consent-google-api