# not receiving "Refresh Token" even in the first consent - Google API

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I'm being redirected to the Google Consent for the first time and asked if I allow this application to manage Gmail account and stuff. And when I'm redirected back, refresh token is null.

```
  +token:"ya29.Gls1BTQIRIuCW2dnzIpQlciOZNpidhjfsoidjfsomethingsm"
  +refreshToken: null
  +expiresIn: 3600
```

I know Refresh Token comes null on subsequent requests. But this was the first request I made.

Is there something I need to do on the console side.

Comment: Solved. I'll close it in two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. I forgot to set `access_type` to `offline`

```
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

In my case I was using `Larave/Socialite`

```
Socialite::driver('google')->with(['access_type'=>'offline'])->redirect();
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer